# newLatLngBounds Method

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In the method

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds,
 int width, int height, int padding);
```

What is the difference between bounds and the width/height ints?

Official doc says that

> Returns a CameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the specified latitude/longitude bounds are centered on screen within a bounding box of specified dimensions at the greatest possible zoom level.

But to me is not clear. Could you semplify it for me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `LatLngBounds` object represents a bounding box on the Earth's surface. The `width` and `height` parameters represent a bounding box on the phone's screen. This method takes the `LatLngBounds` and zooms the camera such that the entire bounds fits within a rectangle of width `width` and height `height` and centers the map on that rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. And the padding ?

Comment: Padding is the space between the edges of the rectangle and the edges of the `LatLngBounds`. Essentially, it just allows you to zoom out or provide some surrounding area in terms of pixels, as opposed to having to figure out how much space you want in latitude and longitude and adjusting your bounds.